# How can I perfect the sentence "Guy explains harmony to people who already know what it is"?

Tags: grammar

I wrote it, and it's bugging me. It smells of bad grammar. I am not concerned about the colloquialism at the beginning ("Guy explains"), but I am concerned about the end ("to people who already know what IT is").

I can see that the "it" is not ambiguous. It refers to "harmony" unambiguously, but the "what" seems like a poor choice.

I don't want to expand it to read "... explains harmony who already know the meaning of harmony".

One option does, indeed, roll off the tongue:

"Guy explains harmony to people who already know what harmony is", but this seems to have a redundant "harmony".

There's this: "Guy explains harmony to those who already know what it is". Still, the "what it is" does not seem correct to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: The trailing “*what it is*” looks fine to me. Do you have a few sample sentences with that phrase that are more ‘obviously’ ungrammatical?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "who already know what it is,"  and I prefer it to your other version.

Comment: My only quibble is that knowing what something is does not imply you wouldn't want to hear an explanation. If this is a case of teaching granny to suck eggs, you need to make that much more clear.

Comment: If the `what it is` bothers you, go with **“Guy explains harmony to people already familiar with it.”**

Comment: "Preaching harmony to the choir", perhaps?

Comment: Who is this 'Guy'?

Comment: @DougWarren But then you wonder if he's talking harmony to people who know about harmony, or if he's literally railing on a specific choir about harmony, because both senses work

Comment: Is this a caption to a picture? A headline? Is it about "a guy" or about a man named "Guy"?

Answer (score 2):

> Guy explains harmony to **those** who already know **its meaning**/usage.

The noun "people" is not wrong in the OP's sentence but it is a little redundant, you explain ideas and concepts to people not to things (normally), the relative pronoun "who" clears up any possible ambiguity. But as far as I can tell, the OP's original proposal is perfectly grammatical

> Guy explains **harmony** to people who already know **what** *it* is.

The antecedent of "it" must be *harmony*. The determiner "what" is used when we want to *know* the meaning of a word "**What** does *harmony* mean?" and when we want to *ask* for a specific word, "**What** is another word for *balance* and *symmetry*?"